# Loading a file using Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file, loops

I am trying to load in a series of strings and doubles (which are in arrays) from a file using an end of file loop. The output is showing the first two lines in the file and giving out an error. Any help/input would be awesome. Thanks.

```
package lab08;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

 public class array {


public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

String mealName[];
double mealPrice[];
mealName = new String [3];
mealPrice = new double[3];


LoadArraysFromFile(mealName, mealPrice);

}

//Load Arrays From File
public static void LoadArraysFromFile(String mealName[], double mealPrice[]
)throws IOException{

    File mealInfoFile;
    Scanner mealFileSC; 

    mealInfoFile = new File("mealInfoFile.txt");
    mealFileSC = new Scanner(mealInfoFile);

    while (mealFileSC.hasNext()){
        int i = 0;

        mealName[i] = mealFileSC.nextLine();
        System.out.println(mealName[i]);
        mealPrice[i]= mealFileSC.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(mealPrice[i]);

    i++;
    }



     mealFileSC.close();

}
```

The File.

```
#1 T-shirt
4.99
#2 Pants
5.99
#3 Jacket
6.99
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+read+file+into+array

Comment: Use `hasNextLine`, read the whole line and then decide how to covert it

Comment: Please, add the error message in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not properly convert the values in your while loop.

I changed this:

```
while (mealFileSC.hasNext()){
    int i = 0;

    mealName[i] = mealFileSC.nextLine();
    System.out.println(mealName[i]);
    mealPrice[i]= mealFileSC.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(mealPrice[i]);

i++;
```

To this:

```
while (mealFileSC.hasNext()) {

       int i = 0;

       mealName[i] = mealFileSC.nextLine().toString();
       System.out.println(mealName[i]);
       mealPrice[i] = Double.valueOf(mealFileSC.nextLine());
       System.out.println(mealPrice[i]);

       i++;
   }
```

It should work this way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to skip the line with the double value then, as you already read the double value with `mealFileSC.nextDouble();` Just add this to the end of your while loop:

```
        if(mealFileSC.hasNext())
            mealFileSC.nextLine();
```

The Output:

```
#1 T-shirt
4.99
#2 Pants
5.99
#3 Jacket
6.99
```